# Linear isomorphism and isometry between real inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry

Let $V$ and $V'$ be real (positive definite) inner product spaces of (same) finite dimensions with inner products $(-,-)_1$ and $(-,-)_2$.

Let $T:V\rightarrow V'$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-linear isomorphism of underlying *vector spaces*.

Then $T$ may not preserve the inner product, i.e. it may not be isometry.

**Q.** Is it always possible to replace the inner product $(-,-)_1$ by 
$r(-,-)$ for positive real $r$, and $(-,-)_2$ by $s(-,-)_2$ so that 
$T$ becomes isometry between $(V,r(-,-)_1)$ and $(V',s(-,-)_2)$?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, let $T$ be the identity map on $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is not an isometry between inner-product spaces with inner products
$$
(x, y)_1 = x_1y_1+x_2y_2
$$
and
$$
(x, y)_2 = 2x_1y_1 + x_2y_2
$$
and multiplying either of the inner products by a scalar cannot fix that.